# Can I change Ciri's fate?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have just finished the main story line for the first time, but I know that the game has many possible endings.

I know there are websites out there with all the steps that you need to take to possibly save Ciri. (I have skimmed over some of these sites) but I basically just want to know if it is possible to save Ciri. Yes or No, without the spoilers on how to save her.

Comment: This title is a bit (a lot actually) spoilery for those who haven't played or finished the game yet. Can you edit your answer to fix this, please?

Comment: The Witcher has been out forever. The asker asked a question, and didn't dance around it. That's fine. At most, an edit should change the title. Adding spoiler tags for a character in the body is unnecessary.

Comment: @Frank - I have to respectfully disagree. The game hasn't been out for even a year yet. Even then, spoilers are not constricted to a time basis. Given that, the title would still be a spoiler to anyone happening across it. I can see why the body would not need to be changed, but I simply did it while I was already editing the title. I'm going to do a quick post on meta for my personal reference :)

Comment: We have Meta posts galore about spoilers. The basic guideline is: does the question make sense without spoilers? If so, then it's fine. I rolled it back specifically because the spoilers made the body confusing without them. The title change was probably a good one.

Comment: @Frank - I will re-edit and just do the title. Leaving the body untouched.

Comment: I can agree with all your points but you also need to understand that rids questions title was chosen with the intent of helping other future players. A vague title such as "can you save this character" only helps me. The braids of stack overflow is helping other people. Who ever else asks this question will most probably Google for an answer as i did. Difference is... now they won't find it

Comment: They should be able to find it, actually.  SEO doesn't just look at the title; it takes the body into account, too.

Comment: **RULE OF THUMB**: if the only way you can think of to remove spoilers from a question title is by removing all of the nouns, *it's not a good question title,* and you should probably leave the 'spoiler.'

Comment: The only problem is that there are two points where you can potentially save her, someone might be thinking of the first case but then end up being spoiled by the ending.  I think the word 'ending' should be added to the question in some form to make this clear.

Comment: @Frank I hear what you are saying, but if I was on google and I saw multiple sites giving methods into how to save Ciri and 1 arbitrary link had the title "Can you save this character" I wouldn't even bother clicking on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're just asking for a yes or no answer, I can help you out:

Yes. I have done one complete playthrough (halfway through my second) and Ciri did survive.

Answer (score 2):

Her life depends on her self esteem/happy memories.

You are given 5 (or so) opportunities to either build up her self esteem or be preachy/dismissive.  Get better than half of them "right" & she survives.  The snowball fight is a rather nice change from bisecting bandits.

> Though if we were on the [parenting site](http://parenting.stackexchange.com), I'm not sure I would encourage being a horse thief with one's ward.

So, go forth & try to be a supportive foster father.

> Oh, and Gerault's dream sequence during the tutorial has no effect on on Ciri's memories.  Feel free to be a jerk in your own dreams.